# Get a org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job from a job already completed on the JobTracker

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` to create/submit/run a MR Job (Cloudera3, 20.2), and after it completes, in a separate application, I'm trying to get the Job to grab the counters to do some work with them so I don't have to re-run the entire MR Job every time to test my code that does work.

I can get a `RunningJob` from a JobClient, but not a `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job`. RunningJob gives me Counters from the mapred package, while Job gives me counters from the mapreduce package. I tried using `new Job(conf, "job_id")`, but that just creates a blank Job in status `DEFINE`, not `FINISHED`.

Comment: Please format your question the next time with the code sample tags, it helps to get a better reading.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see where it does look better, thanks, will do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a how I do it :

```
package org.apache.hadoop.mapred;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC;

public class FinishedJobHelper {

    public static Counters getCounters(String jobTrackerHost, int jobTrackerPort, String jobIdentifier, int jobId) throws IOException {
        InetSocketAddress link = new InetSocketAddress(jobTrackerHost, jobTrackerPort);
        JobSubmissionProtocol client = (JobSubmissionProtocol) RPC.getProxy(JobSubmissionProtocol.class, JobSubmissionProtocol.versionID, link, new Configuration());
        return client.getJobCounters(new JobID(jobIdentifier, jobId));
    }
}
```

The package should be `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` (don't change it) since `JobSubmissionProtocol` is protected interface. The problem with this method is you can't retrieve jobs that are "retired". So I prefer not relaying on this and push the counters as soon as the job completes.

```
...
job.waitForCompletion(true);
//get counters after job completes and push them elsewhere
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
...
```

Hope this would help.